# Laravel how to validate array inside array and create model

Tags: laravel

I can't get access array of images which are inside of an objects array.

```
$this->validate($request, [
   'blocks.*' => 'array|required',
   'blocks.*.position' => 'required|integer',
   'blocks.*.block_title' => 'required|max:100',
   'blocks.*.block_text' => 'required|max:500',
   'block.*.images' => 'required',
   'block.*.images.*' => '|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,svg|max:10240',
]);
```

It also fails in the following snippet:

```
$blocks = $request->blocks;
foreach ($blocks as $block) {

$images = $request->file('blocks.images');
```

I also tried the following:

```
$images =$block['images']; //not work
$images = $block['blocks.images']; // not work
```

I want to create blocks which have images.

Comment: `$request->file($key)` returns a single file instance, therefore you want an array of files.  `$request->allFiles()` will returns an array with all the uploaded files

Comment: Not helped, not right quantity of images

Answer (score 0):

In the request, you should have `'blocks.*.images'` and `'blocks.*.images.*'` instead of `'block.*.images'` and `'block.*.images.*'`.

To get the images you could try:

```
$data = $request->all();
$blocks = $data['blocks'];
foreach ($blocks as $block) {
   foreach ($block['images'] as $image) {
       // $image should be a file
       $file_name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
       $file = Storage::putFileAs(
                    'path-to-save-file-at', $image, $file_name
               );

   }
}
```